# Distributive conditional types Ordering influence in a union

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The type

```
type Diff<T, U> = T extends U ? never : T;
```

from the [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#distributive-conditional-types) return the difference between unions of types. Why is the position of `f` plays a role in the type? I would expect `f` to be in both type in the following example:

```
// f last position
type T30 = Diff<
  "a" | "b" | "c" | "d",
  "a" | "c" | "f"
>; //type is:  "b" | "d"

// f first position
type T31 = Diff<
  "f" | "a" | "b" | "c" | "d",
  "a" | "c"
>; //type is: "b" | "d" | "f"
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAIglgMwQHgCoBooFUB8UC8UqUEAHsBAHYAmAztlAPxSUQBuEATlAFxEDcUAPRCoAJQgBbAPYcooSPQSdpkovIAWAQ2BQtnaFtq04Ac0paARgBtowadgBQC6KgDMABgKxEKR1CgAIi1AqAAfIMtQiMCAY2ig6kD0fyCQ8KD4jMCEQMccQRFIhMCk53BXNwBGb3gkZFSckvSYqOysmKSUgOCS%20PzC0UC2zpLcoA)

Comment: // Remove types from T that are assignable to U.
What type exactly do you expect from T30 and T31 ?

Comment: My bad, I oversaw the comma last night.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's like the set difference in mathematics; it gives the values from the first type which are not found in the second type.